# How to get count with a selection like $(".... :checked")?

Tags: jquery

I need to get a count of checkboxes that are currently checked.

How do I do that?

`$(".... :checked").count()` doesn't work.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
$("input:checked").length;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
$("input:checked").length
```

Answer (score 2):

[`$(':checkbox:checked').length`](http://jsfiddle.net/8Tw5A/) should give you the required count.

Answer (score 2):

Try this instead:

```
$(":checked").length
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `.length`; for example: `$('#some_id input:checked').length`.

Answer (score 0):

try [.length](http://api.jquery.com/length/) or [.size()](http://api.jquery.com/size/) - they are essentially the same thing.  Each results in the count of the number of elements in the matched set.  Apparently .length is the preferred choice, as it is faster.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `length`.

```
$("#something:checked").length;
```

Comment: No () there - it's a property, not a method.

Answer (score 0):

You can always assign a class to the check box elements and select them using the following syntax:

```
$('input[class="yourCheckBoxClass"]:checked').length;
```

This will give you the total of check boxes selected.